# looping in associative array with column name

Tags: php, mysql

I created associative array as below

```
$query = "SELECT word,meaning1,meaning2 FROM dictionary";   
$results = $db->exeQuery($query);
$arrDictionary = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$arrDictionary[] = $results;
}
```

Then i am iterative through another list of word array

```
foreach ($file_array as $value) 
{

}
```

within this loop, for each word, i need to find meaning1 and meaning2. Tried many ways, but no success.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: please tell the structure and data of `$arrDictionary` and `$file_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$arrDictionary[] = $results;
}
```

should be replaced with

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
$arrDictionary[] = $line;
}
```

and

```
foreach ($arrDictionary as $value) 
{
     echo $value['field_name'];
}
```